# Compiling a Cplex program on Mac via command line

Tags: c++, unix, cplex

I have a MIP model using CPLEX. I am new in compiling the programs in Mac. I was wondering what is the command line to compile such program ? I already installed the CPLEX on my machine. 
Here the command I am using but it is not working:

> g++  -I/<'path'>/CPLEX_Studio1261/cplex/include 
>   -I/<'path'>/CPLEX_Studio1261/concert/include -L/<'path'>/CPLEX_Studio1261/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic  -L/<'path'>/CPLEX_Studio1261/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic hello.cpp -lilocplex -lconcert -lcplex

any help appreciated !

Comment: It seems very unlikely that anything with `static` or `linux` in it is going to work on a Mac. Try finding anything with `.dylib` at the end in the `lib` directory and linking with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used CPLEX myself, but you seem to be tripping up on the following:

```
8.1 add *.h and *.lib path in the "searching path" and "library path"
8.2 add -DIL_STL "in other c flags"
8.3 add -lilocplex -lconcert -lcplex in "other linker flags"
```

I think you need to put the name of your source file (`hello.cpp`) before all the linker stuff on the command-line too.

See link - [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014877398).